# Create a table/tables with with parent/child hierarchy in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hierarchy

Im currently a self-taught programmer, and i know and have worked with noSQL databases.
Right now i want to learn better the relational databases. I'm doing a project for myself and trying to deep my knowledge in here, and i'm kinda confused. My goal is to create a simple database with child/parent hierarchy. I want to create a database for person, in which i will only have access to the identification number(no name, age, or whatever). And this person can have childs or parents or both. How do advice me to structure this. I want to query the table so i can retrieve all the childs and parents of a certain individual. My first thought was to build a table with only the PK(Id_Number) and other table with composite key(FK->Id_Number and Id_parent), but i dont think it would work like this? How should i do it? Do you have any thoughts on this? thank you!

To help visualization (instead of identification number, lets use name), i have this object, how should i store it?

```
 {
  human: "Joe",
  child: [
    {
      human: "Kevin",
      child: [
        {
          human: "Joaquin",
        },
        {
          human: "leticia",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      human: "Mary",
      child: [
        {
          human: "Joaquin",
          child: [{ human: "levi" }],
        },
        {
          human: "leticia",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

The goal is to know all families hierarchies like who is the son, parent and possibly brothers of the kevin for example.

Comment: *database with child/parent hierarchy.* How may parents may have a child?

Comment: A child can have multiple parents, and a parent can have multiple childs

Comment: If so then the relation is not parent-child. It is common many-to-many with external restriction (rings not allowed). You may treat it as parent-child, of course, but this is not correct by fact.

Comment: And where is multiple parents in your sample? PS. Post valid JSON opnly.

Comment: Already updated Akina, thanks!

Comment: *how should i store it?* You may store it as-is in JSON column. You may parse it and store in self-referenced table. PS. This JSON is not valid too.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of modeling a parent relationship between entities is by using one table for the entity (node in the graph), and another for the relationship (arc between nodes in the graph).

For example:

```
create table person (
  id int primary key not null,
  identification_number varchar(50) not null
);

create table parent_child_relationship (
  parent_id int not null references person (id),
  child_id int not null references person (id),
  primary key (parent_id, child_id),
);
```

You can also use a single table, but separating the relationship from the entity gives you the flexibility to account for people having multiple parents (natural, legal, adopted, etc.) and also to account for life changes.

Comment: From the other side this structure allows cycles which cannot be detected by constraint logic...

Comment: It is a good start indeed, thank you! But it seems that is not optimized for my use case, because i want all the relations (parents, childs and siblings) of a certain person in a single query  an this way i can only get the childs of a certain parent_id, or the parents of a certain child_id, and i want the 3 relations for a identification_number.

Comment: @hiun Relational databases can walk the entire graph with a single query and return limited or unlimited number levels, as needed. You probably need to narrow down your question with a specific example.

Comment: @TheImpaler true, i have been trying and testing and you are correct, i can follow with your answer, it works for my needs, thank you a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I created a consolidated hierarchy in AWS redshift.

this will create top to bottom hierarchy for every node in the hierarchy tree

Sample data Schema:

```
create table kpi_dashboard.employee (
 id int,
 name varchar (20),
 manager_id int
 );
```

Insert data

```
insert into schema_name.employee(id, name, manager_id)  values
(100, 'Carlos', null),
(101, 'John', 100),
(102, 'Jorge', 101),
(103, 'Kwaku', 101),
(110, 'Liu', 101),
(106, 'Mateo', 102),
(110, 'Nikki', 103),
(104, 'Paulo', 103),
(105, 'Richard', 103),
(120, 'Saanvi', 104),
(200, 'Shirley', 104),
(201, 'Sofía', 102),
(205, 'Zhang', 104);
```

Generated Table:

```
id  name    manager_id
100 Carlos  
101 John    100
102 Jorge   101
103 Kwaku   101
110 Liu 101
106 Mateo   102
110 Nikki   103
104 Paulo   103
105 Richard 103
120 Saanvi  104
```

Recursive SQL to create the consolidated hierarchy path -

```
with recursive Hierarchy (id,name,manager_id,Path)
AS
(
SELECT t.id,t.name,t.manager_id, CAST(t.name AS varchar(max))
FROM schema_name.employee AS t
LEFT JOIN schema_name.employee AS t1
ON t1.id = t.manager_id 
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t.id,t.name,t.manager_id, CAST(h.Path + '>' + t.name AS varchar(max))
FROM Hierarchy h
INNER JOIN schema_name.employee AS t
ON t.manager_id = h.id
)

SELECT id,name,Path
FROM Hierarchy
```

output :

```
id  name    path
100 Carlos  Carlos
101 John    Carlos>John
110 Liu Carlos>John>Liu
103 Kwaku   Carlos>John>Kwaku
102 Jorge   Carlos>John>Jorge
105 Richard Carlos>John>Kwaku>Richard
104 Paulo   Carlos>John>Kwaku>Paulo
110 Nikki   Carlos>John>Kwaku>Nikki
201 Sofía   Carlos>John>Jorge>Sofía
106 Mateo   Carlos>John>Jorge>Mateo
```